# Angular calculating age from Dob

Tags: angular7

I'm trying to calculate age from dob but when I print age its 0 Here's my code :

I would appreciate some help

```html
let Dob:any = new Date(patientRecord.patient_dob);
let today:any = new Date();
let timediff = Math.abs(today - Dob.getTime() );
let Age = Math.floor((timediff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
console.log(Age);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shared is perfectly fine (at first look).

What makes it not working, MAY BE the input date format. (Because I ran your same code with one change but in plain javascript)

```js
let dob = new Date('12/31/1990'); // mm/dd/yyyy
let today = new Date();
let timediff = Math.abs(today - dob);
let Age = Math.floor((timediff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
console.log("Age: ", Age);
```

Look at the hard coded date format. And the `timediff` calculation logic.

Even if you do `dob.getTime()` the result will still be same.

So, all just points to the input you are passing.

Cheers!

Comment: Even I got the result with a change .I just took out getTime() function .Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

suggest using momentJS to make it simple (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/years/)
you can then do something like:

```js
const dob = moment(patientRecord.patient_dob);
const now = moment();
age = now.subtract(dob.duration()).duration().asYears();
```